# JSP Timingout when doing long job

Tags: jsp, timeout

I have a JSP that takes a csv file and adds the tables in the csv file to a database (simplified description).

The landing page is an html page with a form to submit the file.  When the file is submitted the page redirects to a JSP that does the work.  After the JSP is finished processing the file it returns a html page like this:

```
Line 1: Added Bob to users table - Sucess!
Line 2: Added Sarah to users table - Sucess!
```

This has been working great however I have descovered a problem.  When I upload a larger csv file to my JSP (say 600 lines instead of 200, which should take about 10-30 minutes).  The JSP does not return anything.  It remains on the landing page indefinatly.  I think that this is because of some kind of timeout.  Is there a standard way to deal with this?  I think that there are two solutions although I don't know how to approach either one:

#### Solution 1

Increase the timeout time so that eventually the results will be displayed.  I am not sure if this is the browser or the server timing out.  I suspect is is the server because the browser still says: `Waiting for mySite.com/execute.jsp`.

*The server is Tomcat.*

#### Solution 2

User javascript(?) to refresh the page every second(?) so that the page gets continuously updatted with the progress from the server.  I am not sure what changes would need to be made to the server to accomidate this or if this is a common practice.  A pointer to an example would be helpful.

(I am not sure if this solution will solve the problem or just provide better information about where the problem failed).

Comment: In general, you should process long running requests using an asynchronous approach. What do your logs tell you?

Comment: Any pointers on how to use an asynchronous approach?

Comment: Yep, the client could first upload the CSV and you store it in e.g. a database table, then you tell the client that the file was uploaded successfully. Next, you execute an asynchronous job which processes the (use e.g. JMS or a simple scheduler). Advantage is that you decouple things and have control of how many jobs can process files in parallel. Drawback: complexity on client side as you need a procdure to notify the client whether file processing was successful or not... but it scales!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 2 is better. Another option is,

- Create AJAX requests that will update the page asynchronously when the processing job is done.

If you are ok with refreshing the whole page, you can use

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```

And in your serverside code, you would have to ensure that subsequent refreshes returned with the status of the processing job; instead of the initial invocation of the processing job.

However, if you don't want to reload the whole page, then you would need some Ajax implementation like GWT. It is very easy to write a simple DIV updater using GWT. Just look at the GWT tutorials in google.

Comment: If solution two is better where would be the best place to start?

Comment: Going to accept your answer but would using `  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
   setTimeout("location='status.jsp'", 1000);
  </SCRIPT>` work?  Will that prevent the timeout from happening?

Comment: The meta tag I suggested and the Javascript code you just wrote ; do approximately teh same thing. The difference is that the javascript code can specify any page (not just the current page) as the page to load when the timeout occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [O'Reilly tutorial](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/06/11/jsp_progressbars.html) from a few years a ago.

It explains how to make a status bar like this:

[image]